# How can I exclude files from code coverage from the beginning of the filename

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, glob

Using Jest, I want to exclude files from coverage according to the beginning of their filename, regardless of the depth with which the file sits in a directory structure.

Let's say I have something like this:

- src

  - form

    - controls

      - lookups

        - Lookup.component.js
        - FormLookup.component.js
      - input

        - Input.component.js
        - FormInput.component.js

I would want to exclude any component file beginning with `Form` from coverage. Something like

```js
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
  'src/form/controls/**/*(^Form)*.component.js'
]
```

That doesn't work, but hopefully you get the gist of what it is I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: the regex `Form*[^\/]*.component.js$` seems to be working according to [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/W2GP7u/1)

Comment: @safir apparently that is incompatible with Jest, and targeting the top level directory is just as important as the file name itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the not (!) operator on the collectCoverageFrom setting, and this seems to work for me:

```
collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/**/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.interface.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.mock.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/main.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/library/base/abstract-fetch-data-service.ts',
```

In that case, I believe you can simply add a line:

```
'!<rootDir>/src/form/controls/**/form*.component.js',
```